# How can we get Buddypress to interpret HTML entities correctly?

Tags: html, buddypress

Buddypress messages - specifically the preview page - does not interpret HTML entities correctly. Instead, they display as literal strings.

Does anybody know how to get Buddypress to recognize and interpret HTML entities correctly?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This should help: `bp_get_message_content()` retrieves the message content.

```php
<?php
// Retrieve the message content
$message_content = bp_get_message_content();

// Decode HTML entities
$message_content = html_entity_decode( $message_content );

// Output the message content
echo $message_content;
```